# Git is not pushing changes and asking to pull even if repository is new, why won't a pull request solve it?

Tags: git, github

I'm having this problem for quite some time now. Whenever I try pushing to a remote repository on Github, it always shows me an error (Screenshot shared below).

It says:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Even after making a pull request, I get the same error. This error occurs even when I create a new repository and it asks to pull from the newly created repository.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run `git pull`?

Comment: Note: a "pull request" is something different than running the `git pull` command.

Comment: @GaëlJ I'm Geeting some error saying : fatal "refusing to merge unrelated histories"

Comment: @mkrieger1 Oh yes, sorry  my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Note:** this answer uses GitHub as the example (as that was in the question), but the same thing applies to other web-hosting sites such as Bitbucket.)

You have made *two different first commits*.  Git can handle this, but it's probably not what you wanted.

When you use GitHub's "create a new repository" clicky web button, you're given an option:

- create a totally-empty repository, with *no* commits; or
- create a repository with *one **first** commit*, containing files `README` and/or `LICENSE` and/or `.gitignore` file (the precise names of these files may be slightly different, but those are the current options).

(You're also given a public-vs-private option, but that's not relevant here.)  So GitHub will create a new repository on *their* computers, and then optionally *add a commit*.

When you use `git init` on your own computer—let's call this "laptop" for short—you get a new repository with *no commits at all yet*.

Now, a repository with no commits at all is a little bit weird.  The reason it's weird is this: A *branch name*, in a Git repository, is required to hold the hash ID of some commit that exists in that repository.  If the repository is totally empty—has no commits—then *no branch names can exist*.

And yet, Git wants you to be "on" some branch, and in the new, totally-empty repository, you are on branch `master` by default.<sup>1</sup>  So you're in a weird state: you're on a branch that *doesn't exist*.

Making your very first commit removes the weirdness: now that there is one commit, there can be as many branch names as you like.  All of them will select that one initial commit.

There's one other special feature of the *first* commit.  Every commit in a Git repository remembers the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.  But in a new, empty repository, there *is no previous commit* yet.  So the *first* commit you make is different: it *doesn't* remember a previous commit.  It is, in other words, *the beginning of history*.

Once you have this first commit, you'll make your *second* commit using the first commit as the history behind the second commit:

```
A <-B
```

if we call the first commit `A` (rather than using the big ugly random-looking hash IDs that Git really uses).  Second commit `B` will *point to* first commit `A`.  Then the third commit you make will point backwards to `B`:

```
A <-B <-C
```

The way Git finds the *last* commit is to use a *branch name*, or—sometimes—some other name.  If you have just the one name, `master`, you can only have one *last commit*, like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

But here's the thing: you had GitHub make a "first commit", and then you made *your own* first commit.  These two first commits have *two different hash IDs* (because *every* commit has a unique hash ID).  So in GitHub's Git repository, we have:

```
A   <--master
```

and in yours we have:

```
B   <--master
```

Your history starts (or ends) at `B` and then stops there too; their history starts (or ends) at `A` and stops there, and the two histories never meet up.

The only way you can put this into a *single* Git repository is to use at least two *names*.  For instance, let's use names `branch-github` and `branch-me`:

```
A   <--branch-github

B   <--branch-me
```

This can work: two different names pick out two different "last commit" hash IDs.  You then pick one of them to check out:

```
git checkout branch-github
```

You get the files from commit `A`.  You work on/with them, add a new file, do whatever you like, and eventually add everything back and `git commit` to make a new commit, which we'll call `C`:

```
A--C   <--branch-github

B   <--branch-me
```

Note how commit `B` remains off in its own separate history.  If we now `git checkout branch-me`, Git removes the files that go with commit `C`—they're safely saved forever *in* commit `C`—and extracts instead the files from commit `B`.  You make your changes and commit and get:

```
A--C   <--branch-github

B--D   <--branch-me
```

The two latest commits are now `C` and `D`, and the history from `C` is `C` and then `A` (and stop).  The history from `D` is `D` and then `B` (and stop).

If this is what you want, you're all set: just rename your branch to something other than `master`.  If this *isn't* what you want—if you want a single history—then pick one of those first two commits to "forget".  If you want to forget the commit GitHub made as the first commit, use `git push --force`:

```
git push -u --force origin master
```

This sends your commit `B` to GitHub, where they temporarily add it to their repository, then tells them: *Make your branch `master` point to commit `B`!  Do it now!  Do it even if that will make you forget some commits!*  Since GitHub give you permission to do everything to your own repository,<sup>2</sup> they go ahead and do that, and that makes commit `B` now the only commit in their repository, because they *forget* commit `A`.<sup>3</sup>  So they now have:

```
B   <--master
```

which is the same situation you have in your Git repository, and all is well.

If you want to get rid of *your* commit and use *their* first commit, you can do that instead.

If you want to *merge* the two commits, this is possible, using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.  That's more complicated and probably the wrong thing to do, unless you've set up complex histories in both your own laptop repository, *and* the GitHub repository, and are only now getting around to reconciling them.

If you want to *rebase* your commit onto theirs, that's possible as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Depending on your Git version, you can change this at `git init` time, or even change the default, or maybe you can't change either.  You can always change the branch name later though, as the name is not special to Git itself: that's why GitHub were able to change theirs to `main`.

<sup>2</sup>You can, using the GitHub web interface, *take away* your own permissions.  If you did that, you may need to use the GitHub web interface to give yourself permissions again.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, GitHub don't bother *removing* the commit for a long time (if ever), so if you have saved its hash ID somewhere, you can view it on GitHub using the right URL.  But they won't show it *by default* any more, and it will be hard to find, and won't show up in clones you make.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. It has solved my problem