# Pushing Git repo to Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm having a hard time pushing my git repo to my bitbucket. I've made a local repo and put a folder inside of it. I've tracked and committed the entire folder. Now I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: There wasn't enough information in the original question to answer it, but (presumably after you read [Mohammed Naguib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146161/1256452) and tried it) this became a duplicate of sorts, of [this other question nominally about GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69142101/1256452).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried that. It returned an error that said: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

What you [create a remote BitBucket repository](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-a-git-repository/), make sure you are creating it *empty*, without any file/commit in it.

That way, you first push (`git push -u origin main`) will work.

Answer (score 1):

1- create a remote repo on Bitbucket and set it to public
2- get the remote repo https or ssh  and add it to your local repo
3- add the https/ssh url using
````` git remote add origin <url goes here>```` 4- ````` git push -u origin ```

Comment: I tried that. It returned an error that said:
**Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.**

Comment: this happens when the remote and the local branches and different,you need to try 
``` git pull origin <branch name>```

Comment: I did that, and it still returned the same error.

Comment: Does your remote repo contain anything? was it a new repo ,or did it contain any commits ?

Comment: It has a single commit for a directory containing my homework

Comment: As a final solution I would try ```git fetch --all```.this will fetch all the data from the remote repo without merging it.then you can ```git add .   /git commit then try to push this time`` `

Comment: Still doesnt work. Thanks for trying though.